# How to skip a test case in Katalon Studio

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, testcase, katalon-studio, skip

How can we skip a particular test case in Katalon Studio?

For my application, there are different sites with different requirements, so all the functionalities won't be present in all the sites. I want to keep the script as dynamic so I want the script to skip a few test cases if it does not find few links.

```
 @Keyword
        def ClickonLinkText(String text) {
            try {
                WebDriver webDriver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
                KeywordUtil.logInfo("Clicking Link text")
                if(webDriver.findElement(By.linkText(text)).click()){
                KeywordUtil.logInfo("found")
            }else{
                KeywordUtil.logInfo("Not found")
// Need to skip the test case if not found!!
            }
                KeywordUtil.markPassed("Clicked on link text successfully")
            } catch (WebElementNotFoundException e) {
                KeywordUtil.markFailed("Link text not found")
            } catch (Exception e) {
                KeywordUtil.markFailed("Fail to click on the Link text")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use test listeners for that use case:

1. In Tests Explorer, right-click on Test Listeners > New > New Test Listener
2. In the dialog, give your test case a name ("ExampleListener" in my example), and check "Generate Sample Before Test Case method"
   [image]
3. Check for the desired condition and skip the test case if true:

```
class ExampleListener {
    /**
     * Executes before every test case starts.
     * @param testCaseContext related information of the executed test case.
     */
    @BeforeTestCase
    def sampleBeforeTestCase(TestCaseContext testCaseContext) {
        if(condition){
            testCaseContext.skipThisTestCase()
        }
    }
}
```